# Cron expression for jenkins Job

Tags: java, jenkins, cron, jobs

I want to execute a job in Jenkins at 1.00 am on first Monday of every month.

00 01 1-7 * 1

Is this correct? Though i verified it using below link. Still not very sure.

[test link](http://www.cronchecker.net/check?utf8=%E2%9C%93&statement=00%2001%201-7%20*%207%20test&button=)

Comment: Enter your configuration in the "Build periodically" field in Jenkins, then click outside of the textbox — text will appear showing when this would next execute, and when it would have last been executed.

Comment: `H 1 1-7 * 1` is giving warning. **Short cycles in the day-of-month field will behave oddly near the end of a month **                                                                                But however below one works                                                                       `H 1 1-3 * 7 
H 1 4-7 * 7`                                                                                                               Are two expression different?

Answer (score 2):

You are completely correct. If you would like, you can remove your leading zeroes from your first two numbers like this:

```
0 1 1-7 * 1 test.sh
```

You can read all about cron syntax [here](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/cron/). To the best of my knowledge, Jenkins uses cron style formats but simply enhances it capabilities.

Comment: jenkins cron uses a logical AND for the day-of-month and day-of-week fields, but regular cron uses OR; the effect of this significant change is that you can easily program "run this on the second tuesday of each month" in a single expression using jenkins cron.